How to get around Postman Extension pm.execution.location error in Visual Studio Code
Postman can run pm.execution.location from the desktop version, but throws an error when executed from with the Postman extension in Visual Studio Code.  I use it in a pre-request-script.
Is there a work-around for this?  Is this a version mis-match between Postman and its related VSC extension?

I try it, same situation, pm.execution.localtion, pm.execution.skipRequest() and pm.execution.setNextRequest() are not support in Postman VS Code extension.

Thank you.  Its just as valuable knowing you're not crazy   The easy work-around is deciding how badly you need these actions.  I also use pm.execution.setNextRequest but hadn't hit hit it yet.  A mild adjustment to scripts negates the problem.

pm.execution.location is fairly new, and I'm guessing hasn't made it to the extension yet.  It is included in Newman.  Sounds like a query best posted on the Postman forum in relation to timings.
